# If using symlinks, how can I match filenames obtained in a browserify transform with those obtained after its `sort` pipeline step?

Tags: plugins, transform, browserify, symlink, pipeline

I'm making a plugin for browserify (called [postcssify](https://github.com/vigour-io/postcssify)) which allows you to require styles from your javascript code using `require('./some.css')`. The plugin can then produce a bundle.css with all required styles merged together and also allows you to specify some postcss plugins to run against them (hence the name).

How it works is by adding a (global) transform which "ignores" `.css` files and stores them in separate data structure. Then, when browserify is done going through the require graph (when the `wrap` step in the browserify pipeline flushes), it merges the style files in the right order (which it determines thanks to meta information obtained by adding to the `sort` browserify pipeline step) and produces a bundle.

This all works pretty well, but breaks if I add npm links (or symlinks) to mix (a use-case I want to support). Or rather, it works with npm links (I hacked something together), but not with nested npm links (my hack has its limits)... The crux of the problem is that the transform gets the link whereas the later part of the process gets the resolved file instead (the file the link "points" to), so they don't match up... I've illustrated this problem in a separate project to make it clear: https://github.com/shawninder/browserify-links#readme

How can I match the filenames obtained in the transform with those obtained after the `sort` browserify pipeline step?